# Get replace normal text from word document in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I am inserting some data from my app in a word document and than save it again. The code which I have now works ok for a text which is put in a table in the word document but it doesn't get the text which is not in a table. For example, the 1st page of the word document is not in a table and the code skips the 1st page and goes to the 2nd page right away where there is a text put in a table and it's replacing the text as it should. 
Here is the code I have:

```
Document docc = app.Documents.Open(ref path, ref o, ref readOnly, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);
 docc.Activate();
 try
 {
      foreach (Paragraph p in docc.Paragraphs)
      {
           Range rng = p.Range;
           Style sty = (Style)p.get_Style();                      

           if ((bool)rng.get_Information(WdInformation.wdWithInTable) == true)
           {
                foreach (Cell c in rng.Cells)
                {
                     if (rng.Cells.Count > 0)
                     {
                          string testtt = c.Range.Text.ToString();
                          if (c.Range.Text.ToString().Contains("[Company_Name]\r\a"))
                               //   c.Next.Range.Text = "Sacramento";
                               c.Range.Text = "Sacramento";
                     }
                }
                docc.Save();                        
           }
           docc.Close(ref o, ref o, ref o);
      }
 }
```

I know that this line:

```
 if ((bool)rng.get_Information(WdInformation.wdWithInTable) == true)
```

Gets the pages with tables only, but I want to know the way I can get the data from the page without tables in it and modify the text there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are saving document after changing each cell - there is no need to do so. Second and more important you are closing the document after first paragraph so the next one (paragraph) will throw an exception.

I would recommend to use something like the fallowing code, it replaces all occurrences of "[Company_Name]" to "Sacramento" (in whole document).

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

...

```
object o = Missing.Value;
object oFalse = false;
object oTrue = true;

Word._Application app = null;
Word.Documents docs = null;
Word.Document doc = null;

object path = @"C:\path\file.doc";

try
{
    app = new Word.Application();
    app.Visible = false;
    app.DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;

    docs = app.Documents;
    doc = docs.Open(ref path, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);
    doc.Activate();

    foreach (Word.Range range in doc.StoryRanges)
    {
        Word.Find find = range.Find;
        object findText = "[Company_Name]";
        object replacText = "Sacramento";
        object replace = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
        object findWrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;

        find.Execute(ref findText, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref oFalse, ref o,
            ref o, ref findWrap, ref o, ref replacText,
            ref replace, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);

        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(find);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(range);
    }

    doc.Save();
    ((Word._Document)doc).Close(ref o, ref o, ref o);
    app.Quit(ref o, ref o, ref o);
}
finally
{
    if (doc != null)
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc);

    if (docs != null)
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(docs);

    if (app != null)
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app);
}
```

There are two important things:

1) Never use two dots with COM objects:

```
// might be a problem soon:
app.Documents.Open(....

// better way:
Documents docs = app.Documents;
Document doc = docs.Open(...
```

2) Release them as soon as you won't need them in reversed order:

```
if (doc != null)
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc);

if (docs != null)
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(docs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You'll need to add an else to your large if:

```
else {
    if (rng.Text.Contains("[Company_Name]\r\a"))
           rng.Text = "Sacramento";
}
```

Text is already a string, BTW.

This matches your existing code (because I copied and pasted it), but I think you want something a little different:

```
rng.Text.Replace ("[CompanyName]","Sacramento");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help as well, the advice above yours helped me fix my problem. Have a good day too